# Query from multiple tables based on the table name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have hundreds of tables in SQL where they are named in the format such as `dbo.exampledata_2024-01-01` and a new table is created every week. I want to pull the data I need from either the last 12 tables or the last 3 months based on the dates on the name? Is this possible?

I'm not entirely sure where to start with this problem

Comment: Well the best place to start would be to stop doing that. Its a terrible design. With a relational database you should store the date in the table not in the table name.

Comment: That said you are not the first to have such a design, there are literally 100's of questions and answers out there addressing this very problem. So I would find one that is similar and adapt it to your situation.

Comment: Oh, and given SQL Server 2008 is well out of support, create an upgrade path to a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: Table paritioning  is designed for this purpose. Before its introduction, however, there was 'partitioned views', where if you add a constraint on the date column on each table proving to SQL server that the date will always be honoured, you could create UNION ALL view, and then any select from the view with the WHERE date... would automatically eliminate tables from the query consideration. Check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: To meet your request while using the tables named "as is"  would require **"dynamic sql"** (i.e. a SQL script that will generate the sql for your final query, then run that query) In general reliance on dynamic sql is not good practice and you should look to change the way your data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach makes use of the `information_schema.tables` to locate the tables that match the given naming convention. Note, if the last 10 chars of a table name cannot be converted to a date the script will error. Please consider the following purely as an example of the complexities that will always arise from the multiple table approach you have now:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100);

/* alter the next line to adjust the period e.g. 12 weeks, 60 days etc. */
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE());

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'dbo.exampledata_%'
AND CAST(RIGHT(TABLE_NAME, 10) AS DATE) >= @StartDate;

OPEN table_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @TableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL + 
    'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' UNION ALL ';

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @TableName;
END

CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;

SET @DynamicSQL = LEFT(@DynamicSQL, LEN(@DynamicSQL) - 10); -- Removes the last 'UNION ALL'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;
```

Also note this dynamic query is juat a union of all the tables - you haven't specified any details of what that query should do.